# Ruby+Rspec method's arguments sequence check

Tags: ruby, rspec

I try to test method, what will be happen if coming arguments sequence is incorrect. i have already checked for nil parameter.
my method accept id, new_name and i want to know what to do when parameters are new_name, id

Hope my question is clear.

Method which i want to test:

```
def update_recipe(id, new_name)
  raise ArgumentError if id.nil? || new_name.nil?
  recipe = find_recipe_by_id(id).dup
  recipe.name = new_name
  @storage[id] = recipe
  recipe.freeze
end
```

Here is the rspec code:

```
context 'when argument sequence is not correct' do
  let(:added_recipe) { subject.add_recipe recipe }

  it 'raises an ArgumentError' do
    expect { subject.update_recipe 'Pasta', added_recipe.id }.to raise_error ArgumentError
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are worried about this, use Keyword Arguments: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: Hash parameters That's what i exactly needed thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to what you did for handling nil based on what you know id or new_name should be. For example, making sure the id is an integer.

```
def update_recipe(id, new_name)
  raise ArgumentError unless id.is_a? Integer
  raise ArgumentError if id.nil? || new_name.nil?
  recipe = find_recipe_by_id(id).dup
  recipe.name = new_name
  @storage[id] = recipe
  recipe.freeze
end
```

Comment: Yea but here the problem is what if i send argument like  def_update new_name, id  not as id, new_name  ?

Comment: it might be helpful if you show what your concerns are in code

Comment: Method expect 2 parameter in this order.
def update_recipe id, new_name
end

So what if i use a method like  .update_recipe new_name, id

Comment: Did you notice I changed your code? My changes will make your test pass.

Comment: Yea but im not talking about type checking. lets check my rspec expect code i have send prameters in incorrect order not as method expected. So this must raise an error ?